# Django/python and issues with xlwt locale formatting

Tags: python, django, excel, xlwt

I am using django-excel-view which uses django-excel-response which in turn uses xlwt. I have a scenario where users can switch locale which lets them view floats with a standard decimal point or in some languages a comma decimal point.

When exporting the view as an xls with standard decimal point locale it works just fine, but using comma decimals makes the xls file store the float as text and adds an apostrophe before the number (e.g. '123,45). I have a feeling that ExcelResponse (https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1151/) is not handling the float correctly (see line 43 onwards of the snippet).

What would be the correct xlwt style to apply for the xls to be saved correctly with comma decimals and what is a good way to check whether a value is a comma decimal and should have that style applied? In other words:

```
styles = {'datetime': xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'),
          'date': xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='yyyy-mm-dd'),
          'time': xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='hh:mm:ss'),
          'default': xlwt.Style.default_style,
          'comma_decimal': xlwt.easyxf('????????')}

for rowx, row in enumerate(data):
    for colx, value in enumerate(row):
        if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
            cell_style = styles['datetime']
        elif isinstance(value, datetime.date):
            cell_style = styles['date']
        elif isinstance(value, datetime.time):
            cell_style = styles['time']
        elif isinstance(value, ?????????????):
            cell_style = styles['comma_decimal']
        else:
            cell_style = styles['default']
        sheet.write(rowx, colx, value, style=cell_style)
```

SOLUTION:

I ended up adding an extra check in django-excel-response that does some regex check for comma float values (which are added by django locale as they should be) and then replaces the commas with decimal points.

```
elif (re.compile("^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$")).match(u"{}".format(value)):
    value = float(value.replace(',', '.'))
```

jmcnamara helped point me in this direction instead of messing with locales and xlwt formatting.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a scenario where users can switch locale which lets them view floats with a standard decimal point or in some languages a comma decimal point.

The important thing to note here is that the the thousands/decimal separators for a locale are a Windows setting and not an Excel setting. It is set in Control Panel/Regional and Language Options/Format or similar.

So if in one locale the number format is displayed in Excel as `1,234.56` and in another locale it is displayed as `1.234,56` in both cases **the format is stored** in Excel as the US style: `0,000.00`.

So, when using xlwt, or any other spreadsheet writing module, you should use the US style formatting options (comma for thousand and . for decimal). It will then be displayed in the users locale according to their Windows settings.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `easyxf` but also you can use xwlt style like:

```
# You can change the format to more or less decimals
decimal_style.num_format_str = '0.0000'  


sheet.write(0, 0, 3.18526119, decimal_style)  # Example to write
sheet.write(0, 1, 1.11, decimal_style)  # Another example
```

If you want to use `easyxf` you could do something like:

```
decimal_style = easyxf(num_format_str='0.00')
sheet.write(0, 0, '999.99', decimal_style)
```

You could take a look to this examples for more information [Python: Writing xlwt files](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/python-xlwt-writing-excel-files/)